# In ansible-playbook I'm getting an error 'foo' is undefined running this playbook

Tags: ansible

Any ideas why this happens?

undefined variable - The error was: 'foo' is undefined.  I've tried using test.vars in yaml (test.yml) also.

*test.yml*

```
---
- hosts: all
  roles:
    - test
```

*roles/test/tasks/main.yml*

```
- name: test
  debug:
    msg: "{{ foo }}"
```

*group_vars/test.vars*

```
foo=bar
```

*inventory*

```
[all]
localhost
```

```
ansible-playbook -i inventory --extra-vars group_vars/@test.vars test.yml
```

Comment: Based solely upon what you've written, you put the `@` in the wrong place: `--extra-vars "@group_vars/test.vars"` and related to that the `@` syntax only supports .json and .yaml files, so you'll need to convert your ini-style group vars file into one of those syntaxes

Answer (score 1):

They're called group_vars because they're related to the hosts group name.

- Instead of `[all]` the group name should be `[test]` in the inventory file and in the main playbook.
- The variables file name should be equivalent to the hosts group name and in YAML form `test.yml`
- The variables should be written in YAML `foo: bar`

After these changes, there is no need to pass the file on the command line, because ansible will detect it automatically:

```
ansible-playbook -i inventory test.yml
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer is moving the `@` outside, so; it looks like this:

```bash
--extra-vars @group_vars/test.vars
```